# RC filter with an square wave input (checking my math and find my error, if it is somewhere)

Tags: capacitor, resistors, circuit-analysis, filter, laplace-transform

I've this RC filter circuit (r is connect to earth on the bottom):

[image]

My Vin is a square wave:

[image]

With Laplace transform I derived that:

$$Vout(s)=\frac{r}{r+\frac{1}{cs}}\cdot Vin(s)$$

and this square wave has a laplace transform of $$Vin(s)=\frac{\text{A}\tanh\left(\frac{\text{T}s}{4}\right)}{s}$$

My math (H(x) is the heaviside-stepfunction):

[image]

So, when we substitute that in,in the equation for Vout(s) and calculate the inverse laplace transform, and plot that function I got this:

[image]

> Q: Why do I get (from the theory) this strange output voltage? I choose T=1/50 (so the frequency is 50 Hz) and A=6 and R=1980ohm and C=4.7microfarad

EDIT:

When I make A=-6 and remove the 'floor'part I got this:
[image]

Comment: If you have additional material, please edit the original question rather than starting another one.

Answer (score 0):

As a reality check, just to make sure the initial part of the response is correct:

The initial input is a step of height, A and the response to this is, therefore, \$\small A\frac{RC}{1+sRC}=A\frac{1}{s+1/RC}\$

This inverse transforms to \$\small Ae^{-t/RC}\$, which appears to indicate \$\small A=-6\$. I suspect the remainder of the response shown is correct, but the graph may be incomplete (top half missing?).

Comment: So, $A=-6$ and my work is correct?

Comment: Probably, without having done the analysis for the complete square wave. Also, it seems the 'top' half of the graph is missing.

Comment: I'll look what I can do

Comment: can you look to my edit, is this true?